# Delphi application to dial IP phone. [like Dialer.exe]

Tags: delphi, voip, tapi

I am a little new to Delphi TAPI and Phone integration. So please forgive my greenness.
I am trying to make a Delphi [XE2] application dial my IP phone without using the Dialer.exe

I have successfully implemented the ITRequest::MakeCall method but this passes the call off to dialer.

Is there a way to bypass Dialer and send a call directly to my telephony provider?

my telephony provider is Jive Desktop TSP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit old but I think I can help if you are still interested.

What you want is actually pretty easy. You can use your provider's TSP via the Telephony Service's [Tapi 2.0 interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is quite a read and it may be frustrating because it deals with all kinds of functions that you don't need. All you need is to call 'LineInitializeEx', 'LineOpen' and 'LineMakeCall'. That's it (although for closing you should also call LineClose and LineShutDown). These functions call all be played with in an interface test tool called the Tapi Browser. Download [here](http://www.tapi.info/downloads/Tb20.zip) from [this site](http://www.tapi.info/).

Furthermore, you need the Delphi implementation of the interface. You can download that from the Jedi project [here](http://www.consoftonline.com/backup/BackupDelphi/Delphi7Apps/DelphiInformant/July98/Tapi/TAPI.PAS). One last remark: take some caution when using older implementations as most will be pre-Delphi2010 and may have ansistring type strings.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm just now getting back to this and I can't seem to make it work. I'm getting an error on the LineMakeCall. -2147483605 any suggestions?

Comment: Extremely delayed respons but: -2147483605 is an error const. The [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735988(v=vs.85).aspx](lineMakeCall) page on MSDN states the possible return values, among them this one. It's the [LINEERR_INVALLINEHANDLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735630(v=vs.85).aspx). This means that you did not correctly use the line handle you should have received when you called 'LineOpen'.

Answer (score 0):

The key search term here is SIP.  You need a library for Delphi that supports SIP telephony, which is different from the telephone lines supported by TAPI, and there are a number of such libraries listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349565/are-there-any-good-delphi-voip-sip-sdk-library-component) Stack Overflow answer.  I have had good success with the library from [sipcomponents.com](http://sipcomponents.com) which is not one of those included in the earlier list.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I looked into sipcompnents and the documentation doesn't suggest it can do what i want. 
Basically I'm looking to make my phone place a call to another phone when a phone number is clicked on my application. 
I don't want to turn my application into a soft phone..

Comment: You can do that with sipcomponents.  The demo is a softphone, but the component need not be used that way.  My application can place a call, play a WAV file, capture DTMF, record a message from the called party, place another call and connect the two, and so on.